# Sending SMTP mail in SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Tags: sql-server

I tried using : sp_send_dbmail

But I got the following error:

> Msg 15281, Level 16, State 1,
>   Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 0
>   SQL Server blocked access to procedure
>   'dbo.sp_send_dbmail' of component
>   'Database Mail XPs' because this
>   component is turned off as part of the
>   security configuration for this
>   server.
>   A system administrator can
>   enable the use of 'Database Mail XPs'
>   by using sp_configure. For more
>   information about enabling 'Database
>   Mail XPs', see "Surface Area
>   Configuration" in SQL Server Books
>   Online.

I also tried to use this code to send SMTP mail in SQL Server 2008 R2 EXPRESS:
http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=6699

But I am getting the following error:

> Msg 15281, Level 16, State 1,
>   Procedure sp_OACreate, Line 1
>   SQL Server blocked access to procedure
>   'sys.sp_OACreate' of component 'Ole
>   Automation Procedures' because this
>   component is turned off as part of the
>   security configuration for this
>   server. A system administrator can
>   enable the use of 'Ole Automation
>   Procedures' by using sp_configure. For
>   more information about enabling 'Ole
>   Automation Procedures', see "Surface
>   Area Configuration" in SQL Server
>   Books Online.

I went to the "Facets" to check the security options there, but there is nothing about "Surface Area Configuration"! Is it missing because I am using the Express version of the SQL Server 2008 R2? Or am I going in the wrong direction?

If you have any better code/suggestion for sending mail in SQL Server 2008, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out that the SQL Server 2008 R2 EXPRESS edition has no mail feature supported.

Answer (score 16):

Phase 1: right click on sql server 2008r2 express within ssms/choose facets/choose  Surface Area Configuration/set DatabaseMailEnabled ->true/click ok.Restart the server

Phase2:
You just need to configure some tables within msdb.Here are the tables that need to be configured:

1. sysmail_account -> create a default mail account
2. sysmail_profile -> create a default profile(you will need this with sp_send_dbmail)
3. sysmail_profileaccount -> add related data to this based on 2 profile id
4. sysmail_server -> create a mail server from your email account you will be using to send emails.If you do not know the server type look inside sysmail_servertype.

After updating these table refresh msdb and try sending email using sp_send_dbmail
If you followed all these steps you will be able to send email within sql 2008 r2 express using sp_send_dbmail.
I did 5 tests and it went well.

Talley Ouro
Raleigh 
talleyouro@hotmail.com

Comment: Worked a treat.  Nice one!

Comment: I didn't need to restart after setting DataBaseMailEnabled = true

Comment: Worked for me with SQL Express Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)

Answer (score 5):

With some credit to Tanmaya Thopate from [this site](http://tanmayas.blogspot.nl/2008/11/configure-mssql-database-mail.html), here is something that works in SQL Express on Windows Server 2008:

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp
@account_name = 'MyMail',
@description = 'Mail account for Database Mail',
@email_address = 'sender@domain.com',
@display_name = 'Me',
@username='myaccount@gmail.com',
@password='Password',
@mailserver_name = 'smtp.gmail.com'
```

Mail will be send through gmail with your account myaccount@gmail.com

Now create a profile:

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profile_sp
@profile_name = 'MyMailProfile',
@description = 'Profile needed for database mail'
```

Link the profile to the mail

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp
@profile_name = 'MyMailProfile',
@account_name = 'MyMail',
@sequence_number = 1


EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_principalprofile_sp
@profile_name = 'MyMailProfile',
@principal_name = 'public',
@is_default = 1 ;
```

Ensure SSL is enable, otherwise Gmail will complain.

```
use msdb
UPDATE sysmail_server 
SET enable_ssl = 1
```

And send a mail with:

```
declare @body1 varchar(100)
set @body1 = 'Server :'+@@servername+ ' Test DB Email SSL '
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients='me@mywork.co.za',
@subject = 'Test',
@body = @body1,
@body_format = 'HTML' ;
```

You can view the logs from:

```
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_event_log order by log_date
```

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is for express, but for the record here is what to do for proper sql server (SQL Server 2008 R2):

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1673

- Connect to the server in management studio
- Right click the server
- Click "*Facets*"
- In the Facet dropdown, select "*Surface Area Configuration*"
- Double-click the "*DatabaseMailEnabled*" row to set it to "**True**".

Answer (score 0):

Please execute the following script:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 
GO 
RECONFIGURE; 
GO 
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1 
GO 
RECONFIGURE; 
GO 
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 
GO 
RECONFIGURE;
```

Comment: Answer should contain some more information about what is actually being done, what is the problem, not just an "execute this" solution.